# CSS auto height doesn't stretch when overflow is visible

Tags: css, html, height, overflow

I have a div containing an image that is positioned slightly outside of the box. The div also containing another div with text. When I set the height to auto to allow it to expand with the amount of text the image is clipped and doesn't appear over the edge. I've tried using z-index but this is helping.

Here is what I have:

```
#package {
width: 700px;
height: auto;
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
overflow: visible;
}

#packageinfo {
text-align: left;
width: 200px;
height: auto;
float: right;
}

#package .image {
float: left;
margin-left: -30px;
margin-top: -30px;
z-index: 500;
}
```

Comment: please put it into JSfiddle.net, it gives us something to work with.

Comment: The content that isn't displaying properly is all PHP. I can't show this through JSfiddle?

Comment: @Aotorea: copy the HTML from a rendered view (in your browser) if using a _proper_ browser hit ctrl+u and find the relevant HTML, copy it into www.jsfiddle.net along with the CSS and paste it here :)

Comment: ah yes that would have been a lot easier, that didn't even cross my mind! I've already added an example of what I'm having problems with: http://jsfiddle.net/qB6Ye/10/ I need the light grey background to stretch to the size of the text and button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your code and some error in it.
at the end of the table the td an tr was inverted.

there was missing a div closing tag.

I've fixed that and add a clear div.

here is a link
http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/qB6Ye/11/

Comment: Just a small note. it is always easier to find where our tag are bugging when the code is well indented.